# Correcting aggregated view in streaming data

Tags: stream, streaming, apache-kafka-streams, ksqldb

This question is related to aggregation views of KSQL or stream processing technology. When we are receiving events we are applying group by clause to aggregate them. Now an event comes which is correction to some previous event. This will leave my aggregated view in inconsistent state. This is not an out of order event arrival case. E.g. I have an event (e)which consists of entity id (t), category (c) and quantity (q) attribute.
Following events

```
1) e1 —> t1, c1, q1
2) e2 -> t2, c2, q2
3) e3 -> t3, c1, q3
4) e4 -> t1, c1, q4 correction to e1
5) e5 -> t5, c2, q5
```

My aggregated view will be summation of quantity group by category

```
c1 -> q1 + q3 + q4

c2 -> q2 + q5.
```

c1 now in inconsistent state. c1 should be q3 + q4 only.

Are there any ways to resolve such issues. I know I can keep all events in some cache and then create an aggregated view, but this is real-time data so all my views needs to be refreshed every time.

Comment: Well, how do you differentiate whether q4 is correction for q1 or q3? Is there any specific attribute you compare with?

Comment: The underlying entity id is same in case of e1 and e4. So e4 is the latest and corrected update on that entity id

Answer (score 0):

In Kafka Streams, you might be able to do a `KStream#groupBy()#aggregate()#mapValue()`. The aggregate() would not compute the aggregation but return a Map of id->value. In mapValue() you compute the aggregation over all values of the Map. This way, when the updates arrive, if would replace the old value with the new value in the Map, and mapValue() would recompute the aggregation result correctly.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on this. Are you referring to subtractor example of Stream DSL where in Alice category changes from E to A. In my requirement the quantity changes. I am relatively new to this can you point to some sample code that I can look. thanks

Comment: It'a little different that the case you mention, because here, we use a KStream as input, while the Alice example is based on an input KTable. Maybe, you could use a input KTable though (not sure). I am not aware of any example code for this. :(

Comment: I loaded my data in KTable as keyValue (t1, (c1,q1)), (t2, (c2,q2)). Created new stream with key value as (c1,q1),(c2,q2). Applied group by key on the category and then used a aggregate function. But the aggregation function is emitting the aggregated value on category as when there are update on the base KTable. My flow KTable#KStream#groupby()#aggregate(). It is returning me a key as category and sum of all quantities as value. Did I miss anything when you say it will not compute aggregation.

Comment: What is your key and value? key=t1? In you base table? Also, you can do `KTable#groupBy` without converting it to a stream first (if you concert to a stream first, you loose the update behavior).